# Setting charset for a specific div

Tags: javascript, html, character-encoding

Is it possible to assign a charset for at specific div? So that you can have more than one charset on a page.

I'm currently importing snippets of text to my site via JS, and some of this text requires the UTF-8 charset. To be sure that my text is shown right on every page it is included (Sometimes external sites), I force the metatag  into all the sites.

Is it possible to apply this charset to only a specific div, span or something like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it is not, and it also entirely unnecessary.

The `<meta>` element declaring a charset or, better, the equivalent HTTP header is only there to help the browser correctly interpret the *HTML text*. Once the browser has done so, it constructs a DOM out of it and you may essentially treat the text as having no concrete charset after this point. For all intends and purposes the text exists as *text* in the DOM, not as binary representation which must be interpreted by a charset decoder.

When you're adding new content to the DOM via Javascript, the same ideas apply. The browser needs to fetch the new content via HTTP and the content's encoding should be denoted by an HTTP header. The browser can convert the text from the specific encoding to "DOM text" based on that, after which is doesn't matter anymore what encoding it was in.

Therefore, you can perfectly mix and match encodings from different sources being delivered in separate HTTP responses within the same page/DOM without having to worry about a "global" encoding.

Comment: So, if the external text is on a page where the charset is defined, there should be no problem? Even though the charset is different from the destination?

Comment: Yes. As long as the browser can figure out the charset of each individual piece, usually by its HTTP header, all is hunky dory.

Answer (score 0):

I think, You can't use multi charset on one page, but use an iframe can resolve it the problem.

Comment: The problem with using an iframe, is that I then have to specify and reserve a specific amount of space on the receiving end, to make space for the iframe.
If I could find a way to just send the text, the tat could be placed in a div that dynamically could change size and shape according to the delivered content.

But yes, iframe _could_ solve the issue, it just raises another one for me